# Selenium page source differences between ChromeDriver and PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I’m trying to access the DOM of https://gaming.youtube.com/live, and it’s working fine using the ChromeDriver, but i’m failing miserably using PhantomJS.

The problem is that PhantomJS is loading everything which is in the page_source, but doesn’t seem to process the bulk of the HTML tags.

I looked into where the issue was and it seems as though all the elements between

```
<ytg-app> 
    <ytg-auth-helper> 
    </ytg-auth-helper> 
</ytg-app>
```

are missing in PhantomJS.

When saving a screenshot of PhantomJS I only see the background colors of the site itself, without any contents.

Why is this the case? I’ve tried waiting for the elements to load, edit the service_args, change window size, using different user-agents but nothing seems to work, and I have no idea why.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

url = "https://gaming.youtube.com/live"    
phantomjs_path = 'pathto\phantomjs.exe'
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomjs_path, 
                             service_log_path=os.path.devnull, 
                             desired_capabilities=dcap, 
                             service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=ANY'])
driver.set_window_size(1200,1000)
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
```

Comment: you might face problem if your AUT is responsive in nature. phantomjs starts very small. good idea would be maximize or set size of the window.

Comment: No change unfortunately. I checked the driver logs for the browser and found this:


`[{'level': 'WARNING',
  'message': 'TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating \'document.registerElement("dom-module",DomModule)\')\n  (anonymous function) (https://gaming.youtube.com/s/gaming/1b958dd4/gaming_polymer.js:22)',
  'timestamp': 1492761930485}]`


So looks like some javascript can't load in the headless browser